# convert image from cordova imagepicker to base64

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using the following snippet for my conversion operation (**images from cordova image picker to base64 and store them in an array**) but due to the async behavior, it is assigning same string as of the first image to all images. I tried while loop but then, the app crashed. Any suggestion how can I solve this problem.

**Edit: results[ 0 ] is defined but all other results[ i ] are 'undefined', hence image source remains same for all iteration**

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
  function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.src = results[i];
      img.onload = function(){
          var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.createElement('canvas');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.height =  img.height;
          canvas.width =  img.width;
          ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0);
          var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice(23);
          Attachments.push(dataURL);  // array for storing base64 equivalent of all images
          canvas = null; 
      };
    }
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you sure the dataURL you are getting for 2 images is the same. Because it starts with the same string `'data:image/jpeg;base64,...`. I know dumb thing to verify but don't mind. If it is different, you might have to stop the loop till the first image gets converted to base64. To see if the stopping/waiting will work or not, give it some UI control. E.g. try having a button on UI and press it only after 1st image conversion happens. And it's onclick event will have the conversion code. Could you check if it works. Also, display that image somewhere in <img> tag on UI.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni yes I displayed it in my HTML and it display the same image again, it is confirmed that it is only giving the first URI for all images. Your approach might work but that is not my requirement. Is there any workaround for this only?

Comment: I asked you to just test that out, if it works. So we know for sure that some variable like `canvas` or `ctx` are not getting cleared. Also, I just realized, could you add `console.log("DataURL for results index - ",i, " is : ",dataURL);` before `Attachments.push(dataURL)` and see if it's the same URL or different.

Comment: This will show if there is some `async` problem while doing `Attachments.push(dataURL)`.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni resolved. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**img.src = results[ i ]** starts reading the file at **results[ i ] async**, so when loop continues for **i=1**, **results[ 1 ] is undefined** because the file system is still reading for results[0]. Hence all iteration returns dataURL of the first image.

To avoid it use **callbacks** which solve this problem with the concept of **closures**.

```
 window.imagePicker.getPictures(
  function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
     parent.tobase64(results[i],function(dataURL){
        parent.email_data.Attachments.push(dataURL);
     });
    }

  }, function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  }
}

 tobase64(file,callback){
      var parent=this;
      var img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      img.src = file;
      img.onload = function(){
          var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.createElement('canvas');
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          canvas.height =  img.height;
          canvas.width =  img.width;
          ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0);
          var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice(23);      
          canvas = null; 
          callback.call(this,dataURL);
      }
}
```